# Objective C trigger event from presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter, viewcontroller

This:

```
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:[self aVoid]];
```

Gives me the following error:

> Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'void (^)(void)'

After 'presentViewController' is called I want to trigger another void (aVoid) upon completion.

So what causes the error? How can I make it so this works?

Context: I'm calling a Compose Tweet view, when the user successfully tweets I want to call a feedback void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a block as the last param.  What you have is the code that goes into the block, i.e:

```
[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{
    [self aVoid];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, thats brilliant. Any particular reason why Obj-C demands this?

Comment: The linguistic category for this is closure - basically a way to pass code (and execution context) around as you do with data.  The general block can take params of any type and return any type, just like a method.  It can be placed in collections and invoked any time, maintaining its original scope. (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)